# What is the greatest number of unique keywords you can add to a variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, keyword, c11

I was writing some code in C and I wrote: `static const unsigned char foo[]`. Which made me wonder, what is the greatest number of **unique** keywords (and what are those keywords) that I can add in front of a variable in valid c11?

Comment: `static _Thread_local const volatile _Atomic unsigned long long int`

Comment: see [cppreference on declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations)

Comment: @StaceyGirl Make it a pointer and you could add another `const` that is semantically different from the first. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ...as well as `volatile` and `_Atomic`. And this can be continued indefinitely.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is limited to **practical**, answerable questions, with answers that allow you to solve a *specific problem* encountered in the process of software development. Questions that are games or only for the sake of curiosity are off-topic here.

Comment: (Back in the early days of Stack Overflow such questions were welcome here, but we kicked all the games/quizzes/just-for-fun things out to our sister site [codegolf.se]. There's related discussion on [meta], in the accepted answer to [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394)).

Answer (score 2):

No limits, since you can add any number of `const*` to create a different type:

```
int const* const* /* ... */ const* const* i = 0;
```

<kbd>[Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M7qehf)</kbd>

Comment: Oh that's very interesting, I did not know that! While you are 100% correct, I guess I was looking for unique keywords :) I'll update that question, but good answer!

Comment: @AxelMunoz: `unsigned long long` is different from `unsigned long`; you can't simply say "no repetition".

Comment: That's a very good point! I'm not sure how to quite phrase the sentiment where the repetition of `const` is "cheating", but `long long` is okay. I guess no repetition of keywords that have no additional effect.

Comment: @AxelMunoz how about now? Each `const*` creates a different pointer type, has an "additional effect"

Comment: *you can add any number of `const*`* [The C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1) only says "at least 12".

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's of course an implementation limitation, and this one is a theoretical question.

Comment: You don't even need pointers for this. `int const const const i = 0;` etc is valid too. Declarations isn't the most rational part of the C language...

Comment: @Lundin This answer originally had your version (see the [1st revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63034189/1)). OP then [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034068/what-is-the-greatest-number-of-unique-keywords-you-can-add-to-a-variable-in-c/63034189?noredirect=1#comment111470230_63034189) that they want each keyword to "have an effect", so I added the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I tried what works ([`Proof`](https://godbolt.org/z/z5WeT3)):

`_Thread_local static const volatile _Atomic unsigned long long int a` - 9 unique keywords for a usual data variable.

`_Thread_local static const volatile _Atomic unsigned long long int * restrict const volatile b;` - 12 for a single level pointer variable. Note that the keywords which are equal belong to either the object the pointer point to or the pointer itself (except `long long` which isn't a repetition as rather a type definition).

Since you technically can use an unlimited amount of pointer levels, the amount of keywords should raise exponential to this.

Comment: Are `static` and `_Thread_local` legal for the pointed-to object?

Comment: You can also have more than one level of pointer type

Comment: You can add `_Atomic` to a pointer too.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I can only use the `_Atomic` or `restrict` keyword at the pointer. If I use `restrict` with `_Atomic`, Clang shows me an error saying its invalid while GCC treats it fine. https://godbolt.org/z/G7hnne

Comment: `_Noreturn _Alignas (ptrdiff_t) _Thread_local extern inline const volatile _Atomic void*  (*****restrict a) (register double x[static (unsigned long)(signed short)(float)(enum foo{bar})(char)(_Bool)NULL + sizeof true + alignof false]);` Though true and false aren't keywords... I think it ended up with 23 unique keywords :)

Comment: @Lundin ;-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rules as taken from the [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

1. Zero or one of the following *storage class specifiers*:

   - `auto`

     `extern`

     `register`

     `static`

     `typedef`

   The `_Thread_local` storage class specifier may appear on its own or with the `static` or `extern` storage class specifiers;

   Zero or more of the following *type qualifiers*, depending on what you're qualifying:

   - `const`

     `volatile`

     `restrict` - only valid for pointers to object types

     `_Atomic` - not valid for array or function types

   One of the following combinations of *type specifiers*:

   - `void`

     `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`

     `short`, `short int`, `signed short`, `signed short int`, `unsigned short`, or `unsigned short int`

     `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, `unsigned`, or `unsigned int`

     `long`, `long int`, `signed long`, `signed long int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long int`

     `long long`, `long long int`, `signed long long`, `signed long long int`, `unsigned long long`, or `unsigned long long int`

     `float`

     `double` or `long double`

     `_Bool`

     `float _Complex`, `double _Complex`, or `long double _Complex`

     Atomic type specifier

     struct or union specifier

     enum specifier

     typedef name

   Zero or more of the following *function specifiers* - for function types only:

   - `inline`

     `_Noreturn`

   Zero or one *alignment specifier* `_Alignas` - not valid for bitfields, functions, or anything declared with the `register` storage class or a typedef name

So, you could have atrocities like

```
static _Thread_local const volatile _Atomic _Alignas (void *) unsigned long int * restrict ptr;
```

or

```
extern _Thread_local const volatile inline _Noreturn unsigned long int foo(void);
```